# Should I align a character array before accessing it as 32-bit int array?

Tags: c, arrays, random, memory-alignment

I need to generate incompressible data into arbitrarily sized character arrays
really fast. Thus, good random number generator algorithms such as Mersenne
Twister cannot be used due to poor performance. I have also ruled out the C
standard library random number generator functions as they are not inline
functions so the call overhead is too high and besides, they are not
thread-safe. I have selected the Numerical Recipes linear congruential
generator (a = 1664525, c=1013904223, see
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) as the random
number generator.

Now, the RNG generates 32-bit random numbers yet the array is 8-bit character
array. I could do bitshifts and masks to convert one 32-bit random number into
four 8-bit random numbers, but that's way too slow. Thus, I really need to
access the 8-bit character array as a 32-bit integer array.

I have the following loop (or actually, I have an unrolled version of it
followed by a non-unrolled version of it followed by a final loop to generate
8-bit random numbers in case sz wasn't divisible by 4):

```
while (off+4 <= sz)
{
    uint32_t x = randNr(&ctxlocal); // An inline function
    *(uint32_t*)(ar+off) = x;
    off += 4;
}
```

which accesses the 8-bit character array as a 32-bit integer array. Now, I'm
concerned that the access may be unaligned. This may have two effects: (1) on
non-x86/AMD64 processors, the unaligned access may fail, (2) on x86/AMD64
processors, the unaligned access may be too slow. However, I tested the program
with unaligned arrays on an x86 processor and it wasn't slower than it was with
aligned arrays so the potential effect (2) doesn't seem to apply. However, (1) is still true on RISC architectures. I don't have now access to any RISC machine to test how it would fail on such machines.

Should I add a loop to generate few 8-bit integers to first to make the 32-bit
access always aligned? I'm concerned that the loop would reduce performance
while offering no benefits for x86/AMD64 processors. We're not planning to run
the software ever on non-x86/AMD64 processors.

Furthermore, the actual current use case of the function is calling it for
buffers returned by malloc(), which should be anyway aligned. But somebody,
someday could in theory abuse the function on RISC processors by calling it for
arrays that are unaligned. The results of such abuse depending on the processor architecture may be disastrous.

It's also ok to answer if there are ways to quickly generate incompressible data that are better than the current approach of using the Numerical Recipes random number generator and accessing the 8-bit char array as a 32-bit int array. Note that the program should run on 32-bit architectures quickly too, so proposing a 64-bit random number generator doesn't count as better.

Comment: Recently I read about [this new fast rng called pcg](http://www.pcg-random.org) which would generate higher quality numbers than a simple lcg.  As for alignment, I would definitely do a prealigning step to make the main loop operate on 4 byte aligned pointers.  If the buffers come prealigned from malloc, the prealign step will simply detect correct alignment and skip to the main loop.

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of the [PGC Family generator](http://www.pcg-random.org/) , the algorithm is quite simple and also very fast with a good entropy.
A [video](https://youtu.be/45Oet5qjlms) of the talk describing generator.

Which is also largely better than a simple LCG.

**Answer**

I recently stumble upon [this article](http://lemire.me/blog/archives/2012/05/31/data-alignment-for-speed-myth-or-reality/) as I had the same concerns of cache impact on alignment. which suggest that in *specific* situation access to unaligned data could have a *big impact* on performance.

Comment: Omg you posted the same thing 3 seconds after my comment!  I didn't think anyone else had ever heard of PCG!

Comment: @JS1 Must have watch the same videos, thanks reddit ! or maybe I read your comment and decide to type it in 3secs to reap the imaginary points :)

Comment: Unfortunately, PCG generates only at 4.6 gigabits per second on a 32-bit CPU. That's probably due to the fact that 64-bit arithmetic is used in it. The LCG generates at 19 gigabits per second. Even Mersenne Twister is faster than PCG at 10 gigabits per second. Given that my only consideration is that data should be incompressible, I don't think I'm willing to sacrifice performance by using PCG. I don't think PCG is going to have much success if it's even slower than Mersenne Twister given that the properties of MT have been researched in the scientific literature.

Comment: @juhist http://www.pcg-random.org/rng-performance.html states otherwise with **PGC RXS M XS 32** generating around 30Gb/s

Comment: And, about your article: I think the article did very similar tests to what I did, and on a modern processor no difference was observed. So, I don't think the article suggests that in specific situations access to unaligned data could have a big impact on performance. Although there was an update where the access was 50% slower. I'm not sure if that counts as big. And, most importantly, in my application there seems to be no difference in performance.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I think I have to research PCG more, then. I just used the "minimal C implementation", but perhaps that's not the best implementation then.

Comment: I tested the PCG RXS M XS 32 variant, and it generates on my machine (gcc -O3) at 13 gigabits per second whereas the LCG generates at 19 gigabits per second. This is not at all surprising, given that PCG is simply a post-processing step for LCG: the internal algorithm is LCG and the PCG just post-processes the results of LCG to be more random. So, the performance of PCG should be smaller than or equal to LCG given that it is a post-processing step. I would definitely consider PCG for statistical simulations, but for just generating incompressible data quickly, LCG is good enough and faster.